# A standard result from Euclidean plane geometry

Tags: geometry

If $P$ is a point outside a circle $C$ and $l$ is a line through $P$ intersecting $C$ at $X$ and $X'$, the product $PX \cdot PX'$ is independent of $l$ and is equal to $PY^2$, where $PY$ is a ray tangent to $C$ at $Y$.

I am not sure how to prove this. Upon staring at the picture, I am feeling like the Pythagorean theorem and similar triangles might be the way to go.

[image]

Comment: Consider $\triangle PXY$ and $\triangle PYX^\prime$. The [Inscribed Angle Theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inscribed_angle#Theorem) will help; as will the related formula for computing $\angle P$ from $\stackrel{\frown}{XY}$ and $\stackrel{\frown}{X^\prime Y}$.

Comment: Okay. I know what those theorems are but how will that help us here? We dont even know any specific arc lengths.

Comment: Lack of specific arc lengths isn't a bug, it's a feature! After all, you're trying to prove something true no matter what the arc lengths are. So, ask yourself these questions ... (1) What's the formula for $m\angle P$ in terms of $m\stackrel{\frown}{XY}$ and $m\stackrel{\frown}{X^\prime Y}$? (2) What's the formula for $m\angle YXX^\prime$ in terms of $m\stackrel{\frown}{X^\prime Y}$? (3) What's the formula for $m\angle YX^\prime X$ in terms of $m\stackrel{\frown}{XY}$? Then look at those triangles again.

Comment: (I did not put the arcs above the letters) Okay so we have that the measure of angle $P$ is $\frac{1}{2}(X'Y - XY)$, $YXX' = \frac{1}{2}X'Y$, and $YX'X = \frac{1}{2}XY$. Then, $YXX' - YX'X =$ measure of angle $P$.

Comment: Correct. Now, observe that $\triangle PXY$ has $\angle YXX^\prime$ as an *exterior* angle. You know $\angle P$; so what's $\angle PYX$? (FYI, the arc mark is done like this `$\stackrel{\frown}{XY}$`. One might think there would be an easier way, but ... nope!)

Comment: Come to think of it, the proof is far more straightforward than I've indicated: $\angle PX^\prime Y \cong \angle PYX$ by the Inscribed Angle Theorem alone (since both angles subtend chord $XY$). With that, you're almost done.

Answer (score 1):

Euclid breaks down the proof into two cases; if $XX^\prime$ is a diameter or not.

If $XX^\prime$ is a diameter through center $O$, draw the right triangle $POY$. Then, by the Pythagorean theorem $OP^2 = OY^2 + YP^2$, where $OP^2 = (OX + XP)^2 = OX^2 + 2(OX)(XP) + XP^2$, and $OY^2 = OX^2$. That means that $YP^2 = 2(OX)(XP) + XP^2 = XP(2(OX) + XP) = XP(XX^\prime + XP) = XP(X^\prime P)$.

Similarly, if $XX^\prime$ is not a diameter, take $Y$ to be the tangent closer to $XX^\prime$, and draw the line $OY$, and a perpendicular line from the center $O$ to $XX^\prime$ at $Z$. Similarly, we have that triangles $OYP$, $OXZ$ and $OZP$ are right angled, and that $XX^\prime$ is bisected by $Z$.

Can you finish the proof?